# Heroku App Errors, Nothing in Heroku Logs

Tags: heroku

I'm getting "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

`heroku logs` turns up nothing useful from what I can see...

```
2014-10-06T20:48:04.846089+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-10-06T20:48:06.519972+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-10-06T20:48:07.928530+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Thin
2014-10-06T20:48:07.928582+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:58305
2014-10-06T20:48:07.928584+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-10-06T20:48:07.928586+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-10-06T20:48:07.928587+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-10-06T20:48:07.928589+00:00 app[web.1]: Thin web server (v1.6.2 codename Doc Brown)
2014-10-06T20:48:07.928590+00:00 app[web.1]: Maximum connections set to 1024
2014-10-06T20:48:07.928592+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on 0.0.0.0:58305, CTRL+C to stop
2014-10-06T20:48:07.928593+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-10-06T20:48:07.812908+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 49372 -e production`
2014-10-06T20:48:08.659411+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2014-10-06T20:48:11.589427+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Things work fine locally.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the following got rid of the issue (i thought db migration would happen automatically)

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```